"See how I feel"?
What I’d like to do is get a couple of fights and rent a nice house. You want to go to the gym sometime? Maybe we could work out again, see how I feel. I was in bad shape last time.
Does this mean " if we go to the gym and work out again, then it will become clear if I am in good shape or not" ?
at the beginning of the novel, they meet with each other in the gym. Tully loses to him. The name of this character who wants the other one to go with him to the gym is Tully. He is almost 10 years older than Ernie ( the other character) and Tully somehow is a retired boxer. However, Ernie is at the beginning of his career and tully at the end of it. Afterwards, they see each other again. Both of them want to find a job. So they as farm worker get employed.  they go to the farm and begin to pick up nuts and throw them into bucket and so on. at the end of this work day, Tully says he wants to start his training again in order to get ready for bouts

Can you provide a bit more context? Who are the characters that are speaking and what is their relationship?

@SoroushGh your supposition seems almost correct, from the scant information, but perhaps to see how they feel about shaping up and being able to take on some actual fights.

He sounds depressed. If he goes to the gym, he might feel better.

Please edit to tell more about the situation. It's unclear how the "we" relate to the "I."

@Kaia thank you. I edited the question and explained about the character and their relationship.

@AndyBonner thank you. I edited the question.

@Lambie thats true. he is depressed. But the meaning of " see how I feel" isn't clear and how it is related to the preceding sentence

When you work out, that is, get exercise, you feel better. He means: see if I feel better.

@Lambie thank you. But I think. He means if we go to the gym, then it becomes clear if I can do it / make it or not.

Tully's name should begin with a capital letter as well as Ernie's.

@KateBunting thanks.

It's not terribly clear, as Tully strings together several different thoughts in these sentences. The most likely reading, since the context is about resuming training and re-entering the boxing ring, is that Tully wants to know how he might feel, physically, after a challenging boxing workout, as it might help him decide whether he could still put in more training and compete. OR it could be a shorthand for "I wonder whether I still have 'the feel' for fighting; let me try a bit and see whether it still comes naturally."
It's more unclear what the last sentence, "I was in bad shape last time" means. It could mean "The last workout left me in bad shape, i.e. in distress, and I'm worried that the next might too." Or hopeful that the next won't. OR it might mean "You beat me last time because I was in bad shape [i.e. poor physical condition or training]. Maybe you won't beat me so easily this time."

Thank you so much. For the first time when they met with each other in the gym, Tully invited him to box. And he told Ernie " I'm all out of shape now..." and the last sentence you mentioned above that is unclear refers to this sentence.

The use of "see" in connection with other senses is very common in colloquial English, and could be taken, in that context, to mean perceive.
Some examples:

"Add more salt and see how it tastes."
"Why don't you see how it feels when you fall on ice?"
"Play it slower and see if it sounds better."
"Sniff the dog to see if the skunk odor has worn off."

Yep, that usage does seem puzzling, when one stops and looks at it... umm, thinks about it.

Thank you for your answer.
